# How to set cookie in laravel ajax request

Tags: laravel

I have a search form in laravel and I want to save filtered values in cookie in laravel.

I have followed the laravel tutorial and tried to set cookie like this :

```
$request->cookie('name', json_encode($_POST), 84600);
```

But it is not saving cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `cookie` method on the request is only for retrieving a value.

If you want to add a value to the upcoming response you can use the [queue()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#cookies) method with the `cookie()` helper function:

```
cookie->queue('name', json_encode($_POST), 84600);
```

Answer (score -1):

Using javascript try

```
$.cookie("name", JSON.stringify($("#youcookiesId_hidden filed").data()));
```

Comment: javascript + jquery you mean